# doctrine 2 - removing all elements from arraycollection does not invoke any Event

Tags: symfony, events, doctrine-orm, arraycollection

I need to invoke event when arraycollection is cleared (has no elements), pre/postUpdate is not invoked then. Only if I change contents of arraycollection and there is at least one element after change pre/postUpdate events are invoked.

Any Idea how to make it work?

Comment: can you post your pre/postUpdate event and the file that triggers the event?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $em     = $args->getEntityManager();

    if ($entity instanceof Track) {
        // remove all old statuses
        $query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT os
             FROM CuculoERPBundle:OrderStatus os
             WHERE os.track = :track'
        )
            ->setParameter(':track', $entity->getId());

        $orderStatusArray = $query->getResult();

        foreach ($orderStatusArray as $orderStatus) {
            $em->remove($orderStatus);
        }

        // add new statuses
        foreach ($entity->getOrders() as $order) {
            var_dump($order->getId());
            $orderStatus = new OrderStatus();
            $orderStatus->setOrder($order);
            $orderStatus->setTrack($entity);
            $orderStatus->setStep($em->getReference('Cuculo\ERPBundle\Entity\OrderStep', 6));

            $em->persist($orderStatus);
        }

        $this->needsFlush = true;
    }//end if
}//end postUpdate()
```

I managed to do this by copying code after // remove all old statuses to UpdateAction and adding conditional to count ArrayCollection and if 0 exec this code.